# Best way to load .txt file?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm practicing by building a simple app with 20 .txt files that I have add to the app. Here's what I have so far:

1. Created tableviewcontroller with nav embedded and a detail view
2. List the titles of the .txt files with filemanager in tableview

I'm stuck on trying to load the .txt files into textview when a .txt tile is selected. I tried using a func load but then get stuck on how to call load when .txt title is selected. Can anyone help or link me to something that explains this?

Ideally I'd like to add .txt files in a way that allows more flexibility than just adding text bodies. These are poems in a foreign language and I'd like to add translations after each line that can toggled on and off. Anyone know how I could that and if the direction I've taken so far is the best way to get there? Should I be calling the files in some other way?

Here is my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var hymns = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

        for item in items {
            if item.hasSuffix(".txt") {
                hymns.append(item)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return hymns.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Hymn", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = hymns[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
            vc.selectedHymns = hymns[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

And this is my detailViewController so far:
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var selectedHymns: String?
    var hymnText = [String] ()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let textToLoad = selectedHymn {
            if let hymnText = load(file: textToLoad){
            textView.text = hymnText
        }

    }
    }

    func load(file name:String) -> String {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "txt") {
            if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {
                return contents
            } else {
                print("Error! - This file doesn't contain any text.")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error! - This file doesn't exist.")
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you would like to edit the text you would need first to move/copy them out of your app bundle folder which is read only

Comment: Thank you. I just want the text to be read only. I have unselected editable in identity inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `hymns` array contains **full string paths** and you are going to load the contents with `path(forResource` which expects a **file name** (the last path component of a string path).

I highly recommend to use always the URL related API and display the file name in the table view cell.

- Declare the data source array as array of `URL`

  ```
  var hymns = [URL]()
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` you can replace the code with one line

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      hymns = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "txt", subdirectory: nil)!
  }
  ```

  the method returns the URLs of all files with the given extension in the bundle
- In `cellForRow` you could display just the file name

  ```
  cell.textLabel?.text = hymns[indexPath.row].lastPathComponent
  ```

  You could even strip the extension

  ```
  cell.textLabel?.text = hymns[indexPath.row].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
  ```
- In the `DetailViewController` create the property `selectedHymn` (better in singular form) as `URL`

  ```
  var selectedHymn : URL!
  ```
- Of course then you have to change the line to send the URL in `didSelectRowAt` in the first view controller to

  ```
  vc.selectedHymn = hymns[indexPath.row]
  ```
- Now you have the URL of the file which can be used directly to load the text

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let hymnText = try! String(contentsOf: selectedHymn )
      textView.text = hymnText
  }
  ```

  The `load(file` method is not needed at all. The URL – retrieved with the `urls(forResourcesWithExtension` method – is 100% guaranteed to exist and the forced `try!` is safe. The other optional bindings are not needed, too

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. I will use URL here on out. A question about using UIScrollView instead of UITextView. If I change out the UITextView for UIScrollView, it gives me an error for scrollView.text = hymnText. I read that UITextView is a child of UIScrollView, so shouldn't I be able to use .text as a property? Is the only way to do this to put a UITextView inside of a UIScrollView?

Comment: You can use  `UITextView` alone or in an `UIScrollView`. But you cannot use `UIScrollView` alone.

Answer (score 0):

try this to load file data

```
func load(file name:String) -> String? {
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "txt") else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            return contents
        }
        catch {
            print("Read Error")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

You can use

```
if let data = self.load(file: "YourFileName") {
    print(data)
}
```